# Как выполнить перенаправление с GETпараметром на эту же страницу но без GET параметра

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать перенаправление с мойсайт.ру/?p=17
на мойсайт.ру

В гугле примерно одинаковые инструкции.

переделал под себя получил такие строки

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=17
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

После загрузи страницы получаю сообщение что сайт выполнил перенаправление слишком много раз. Что делаю не так, как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Проверил на Apache2 локального хоста - работает без ошибок